# Build hangs with an even modest filesize

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a C++ program with a large vector which is stored in a header file.

This vector has a size of around 1 million floats. (approx 5MB filesize). I am unable to build this program in Visual Studio. The build files are generated by cmake.

If I replace this vector by a smaller vector say of size 100, my program builds just fine in minutes. But even with half a million points, the program does not build even if left for several hours.

My question, how do I get the program to build with my 5MB file. Does MS Visual studio place any restricitions on filesize or heap size ? On Linux I could make the program in around 5 minutes of time. But no luck with Visual studio.

Some where it suggested to use this environment variable.

`CL =  /Zm50`

I tried this with various numbers but none of it makes any difference.

Visual Studio gives no  details - the build simply gets stuck on the large file and won't complete. And I am hoping some one with experience with Visual studio can give some insights on possible build options.

Comment: Sounds like you're using the compiler to do a compile-time calculation on the array. Maybe don't do that?

Comment: @Taekahn- not doing any compile time calculation on the vector. All calculations happen at runtime and they too are very modest calculation. It builds and runs absolutely fine on a very old Linux machine. And my Windows machine is much more powerful in terms of specs.

Comment: Not sure then, sorry!

Comment: By "vector" do you mean `std::vector<float>` or `float data[] = {...};`?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm - it is `std::vector<float>`

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?  Otherwise all anyone can do is guess.

Comment: Can you change it to use something like `static const float data[] = {...}; std::vector<float> bigvec = {std::begin(data), std::end(data)};`, putting that code in a .cpp file (and not a .h that is included in multiple files)?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm - let me try

Comment: @G.M - a minimum reproducible example in this case would have to be a file of 5MB size - a vector of floats. Like i said, it works great with small programs

Comment: So the vector effectively has a 5MB (approx) initializer list?

Comment: @G.M. yes it is just that.

Comment: Worth putting a in a little stubby version of what you are doing into the question along with a "This isn't enough data to cause the problem" caveat. This adds a lot of clarity the question is missing even though it's not-reproducible.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm - Man that suggestion did the trick. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've indicated in comments that you're using `std::vector<float>` with an initializer, you can replace that with a static array:

```
static const float data[] = {...};
std::vector<float> bigvec {std::begin(data), std::end(data)};
```

that you declare once in a .cpp file.

The static array can be completely constructed at compile time, and does not require any code generation. Defining it in a source file (rather than a header that can be included multiple times) will avoid having a massive amount of duplicated code and/or data for the linker to deal with (as well as a possible One Definition Rule violation).